# Pine script getting the time when a trailing stop was triggered

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to display the time when a trailing stop loss was activated on a trade.

Here is how I have set up my exit order

```
MS_IN_1H = 1000 * 60 * 60
msOffsetInput = 1*MS_IN_1H // "1" because I am in GMT+1


strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Enter Long", trail_points=50, trail_offset=50, comment_trailing = str.format("\n\n  {0,date,HH:mm:ss yyyy.MM.dd}", time + msOffsetInput))
```

But this seems to show only the time when the current bar started...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your strategy.exit command record the time at the creation of the strategy.exit, so you won't have the time of its execution.
Try to activate calc_on_every_tick and use strategy.wintrades and strategy.losstrades to detect the instant when the trade closed.

```
var NbWin = 0
var NbLoss = 0
if strategy.wintrades > NbWin
    NbWin := strategy.wintrades
    // Here you can use a label to write what you want.
    label.new(bar_index, close, yloc=yloc.abovebar, text = str.format_time(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", syminfo.timezone))
else if strategy.losstrades > NbLoss
    NbLoss := strategy.losstrades
    label.new(bar_index, close, yloc=yloc.abovebar, text = str.format_time(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", syminfo.timezone))
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, it seems to be the right thing to do indeed